# Как создать динамическую ссылку на ячейку в Excel?

Tags: excel, google-docs

У меня есть таблица где много строк, и какие то строки являются заголовками к нижеидущим. Я сделал новый лист, где хочу сделать Оглавление с ссылками, переходя по которым можно сразу переместится к нужной строчке на основном листе. Когда я создаю ссылку она направляет на заданную строку, но когда я добавляю новые строки в таблицу ссылка съезжает. Как можно сделать фиксацию ссылки к заданному значению?

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Также прилагаю [*GIF*](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5lEcR.jpg) для более наглядной демонстрации проблемы

Comment: "Ячейка-заголовок" чем-то отличается от "ячейки-нижеидущей"? Шрифт, цвет фона, символ-маркер в тексте (например §)? Если никакой разницы нет, то задачу автоматизировать вряд ли получится - только Вы знаете, что это заголовок, а электронной таблице это не известно. Возможно, использование функции HYPERLINK() с нетривиальным формированием первого параметра и стало бы приемлемым решением, но это скучно - время и силы, затраченные на формирование таких ссылок, можно использовать на что-нибудь более интересное

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Вы можете использовать именованные диапазоны. Добавляете диапазон на вашу ячейку на которую вам надо ссылаться. Потом в оглавлении правой кнопкой - ссылка, делаете ссылку через именованный диапазон. Тогда при добавлении столбцов/строк, именованный диапазон тоже меняется и ссылка всегда ведет на нужную ячейку.
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Правка: Можно не делать именованные диапазоны, а просто делать ссылку на ячейку. Т.е не получить ссылку и ее вставлять в оглавление, а в оглавлении сделать ссылку на ячейку, тогда она сдвигается при добавлении строк/столбцов

Comment: спасибо за исчерпывающий ответ, все работает